# cannot find package "io/fs" in any of

Tags: fabric, chaincode

：installing chaincode failed: Multiple errors occurred: - Transaction processing for endorser [localhost:7051]: Chaincode status Code: (500) UNKNOWN. Description: chaincode installed to peer but could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image build failed: docker build failed: Error returned from build: 1 "/chaincode/input/src/github.com/fyx_chain.com/fyx_chain/chaincode/vendor/golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:19:2: cannot find package "io/fs" in any of:
/chaincode/input/src/github.com/fyx_chain.com/fyx_chain/chaincode/vendor/io/fs (vendor tree)
/usr/local/go/src/io/fs (from $GOROOT)
/chaincode/input/src/io/fs (from $GOPATH)
/go/src/io/fs
" - Transaction processing for endorser [localhost:7151]: Chaincode status Code: (500) UNKNOWN. Description: chaincode installed to peer but could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image build failed: docker build failed: Error returned from build: 1 "/chaincode/input/src/github.com/fyx_chain.com/fyx_chain/chaincode/vendor/golang.org/x/net/http2/transport.go:19:2: cannot find package "io/fs" in any of:
/chaincode/input/src/github.com/fyx_chain.com/fyx_chain/chaincode/vendor/io/fs (vendor tree)
/usr/local/go/src/io/fs (from $GOROOT)
/chaincode/input/src/io/fs (from $GOPATH)
/go/src/io/fs

I try to make go version from 1.19 to 1.17,besides u try to write docker-config.yaml to make go reflect to docker containers(peer), and u try to make docker images version from latest to 2.2 ,but have the same question (fabric 2.2)